# I am trying to merge the two sorted linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here I am trying to merge two sorted linked lists but my code is not working at all so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is the function which does the job of merging two sorted linked lists

```
   Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)

     {

     Node *temp,*ptr,*par;
      ptr=headA;
    par=headB;
    int c=0,s=0,t;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
        ptr=ptr->next;
        c++;
    }
    while(par!=NULL)
        {
        par=par->next;
        s++;
    }
    t=c+s;
    //cout<<t<<"\n";
    temp=(Node*)malloc(t*sizeof(Node));
    if(headA->data <= headB->data)
        {
        temp=headA;
        ptr=headA->next;
        par=headB;
    }
    else
        {
        temp=headB;
        par=headB->next;
        ptr=headA;
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL && par!=NULL)
        {
        if(ptr->data>=par->data)
            {

            temp->next=par;
            par=par->next;
        }
        else
            {

            temp->next=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
        temp->next=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    while(par!=NULL)
        {
        temp->next=par;
        par=par->next;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=NULL;
     while(temp!=NULL)
        {

       cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Tag your question with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: The "standard" method uses a pointer-to-pointer, and takes about ten lines of code.

Comment: *"my code is not working at all"* is not an appropriate problem description. What part of the code isn't working? Do you get an error? Does it return the wrong results? What inputs are you trying it with, and what would the correct results look like?

Comment: @SumitKapoor are you just merging two lists which are sorted or do you want to merge the two lists and sort the entire list?

Comment: @CherubimAnand I am trying to merge two sorted lists

Comment: @SumitKapoor don't you want to sort the list after it's merged?

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a pointer based dynamic data structure.

The main mistake you did is allocating **a huge consecutive heap memory** as if your new linked list is an **array**.

So, the solution is completely wrong after that point.

Code below should merge two sorted linked lists in sorted order and return a pointer to the new linked list.

```
Node* tempA, *tempB, *newTemp, *newHead;
tempA = headA;
tempB = headB;

newTemp = (Node*) malloc( sizeof(Node));
newHead = newTemp;

while( tempA && tempB)
{
    if( tempA->data <= tempB->data){
        newTemp->data = tempA->data;
        tempA = tempA->next;
    }
    else{
        newTemp->data = tempB->data;
        tempB = tempB->next;
    }

    newTemp->next = (Node*) malloc( sizeof(Node));
    newTemp = newTemp->next;
}

while( tempA)
{
    newTemp->data = tempA->data;
    tempA = tempA->next;

    newTemp->next = (Node*) malloc( sizeof(Node));
    newTemp = newTemp->next;
}

while( tempB)
{
    newTemp->data = tempB->data;
    tempA = tempB->next;

    newTemp->next = (Node*) malloc( sizeof(Node));
    newTemp = newTemp->next;
}

free(newTemp); //last one is useless.

return newHead;
```

Comment: your sol is a sorted list. @Sumit Kapoor, as per me you wanna add second list at the end of first one, right pal ?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node; 

int add( Node **head, int value )
{
    Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );   
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->data = value;

        if ( *head == NULL || value < ( *head )->data )
        {
            tmp->next = *head;
            *head = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            while ( ( *head )->next && !( value < (*head )->next->data ) ) head = &( *head )->next;

            tmp->next = ( *head )->next;
            ( *head )->next = tmp;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void display( Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next ) printf( " %d", head->data );
    printf( "\n" );
}

Node * MergeLists( Node *headA, Node *headB )
{
    Node *headC = NULL;
    Node **tailC = &headC;

    while ( headA && headB )
    {
        *tailC = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

        if ( *tailC != NULL )
        {
            if ( headB->data < headA->data )
            {
                ( *tailC )->data = headB->data;
                headB = headB->next;
            }
            else
            {
                ( *tailC )->data = headA->data;
                headA = headA->next;
            }

            tailC = &( *tailC )->next;
        }           
    }

    while ( headA != NULL )
    {
        *tailC = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

        if ( *tailC != NULL )
        {
            ( *tailC )->data = headA->data;
            headA= headA->next;
            tailC = &( *tailC )->next;  
        }
    }

    while ( headB != NULL )
    {
        *tailC = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

        if ( *tailC != NULL )
        {
            ( *tailC )->data = headB->data;
            headB= headB->next;
            tailC = &( *tailC )->next;  
        }
    }

    return headC;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    Node *headA = NULL;
    Node *headB = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) add( &headA, rand() % N );
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) add( &headB, rand() % N );

    printf( "List A:" ); display( headA );
    printf( "List B:" ); display( headB );

    Node *headC = MergeLists( headA, headB );
    printf( "List C:" ); display( headC );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
List A: 1 3 3 3 3 4 7 8 9 9
List B: 0 0 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 9
List C: 0 0 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9
```